# Increase mongoDB cursor.batchSize()

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

Using parse to call 105 fields in my mongoDb but only 101 are coming through.
How do i increase mongoDb default value for cursor.batchSize()?

Answer (score 0):

DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 1000;

Comment: was this a mongoshell thing, or was this a setting in a driver, such as the Java driver?

Comment: this was a. mongo command i used, connected to my mongo db and simply used that command

Comment: how did you connect to the mongoDB database, what tool did you use?

Comment: I'm currently using parse server, that connects to mongodb.
so i use CMD to connect to azure to connect to my dokku container.
If you using this I can send you my steps to log in.

Comment: Hmm, so your stack looks like: application -> parse server -> azure -> dokku -> mongodb?